# Получение HTML кода страницы после выполнения Javascript и др. клиентских скриптов в PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, render

Есть проблематика проверка внешних(относительно PHP) html страниц, например на наличие нецензурных выражений, которые может увидеть пользователь, в окне своего браузера ! Например в страницу example.com/index.html встроен код

```
Переменная1 = Нец
Переменная2 = ензу
Переменная3 = ра
document.write(Переменная1+Переменная2+Переменная3);
```

И сами видите, что получается - что видит пользователь!

Что было изучено до написания вопроса :
1. PhantomJS - выдает идеальную картинку в PDF, т.е. правильно рендерит html страницу - но у меня нет возможности анализировать полученные PDF файлы. Функция page.content в разных вариантах:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://www.phantomjs.org', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log(page.content);
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(page.content);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 20000); // Change timeout as required to allow sufficient time 
    }
});
```

Выдает ТОЛЬКО концовку html файла, а так как документации по PhantomJS - НЕТ, то соответственно ничего не могу сделать.

И третье для вызова phantomJS  нужно создавать JS файлы, что также выглядит очень криво.

Прошу подсказать как добиться чтения html после выполнения Javascriptov внутри PHP(freebsd) т.е. мне нужно получить строку содержащую ТЕКСТ, ССЫЛКИ на внешние объекты (т.е. URL) HTML форматирование внутри PHP.

Comment: не знаю как собираетесь использовать это, но как вариант - использовать selenium. Вы получаете доступ к странице в браузере прямо в php. Примеры можно посмотреть [здесь](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/selenium-rc) Вообще это для тестирования используется, но вдруг вас и такой вариант устроит

Comment: [Как это нет документации](http://phantomjs.org/documentation/)? А передавать код можно и пайпом.

Comment: Silenium не подходит это решение для тестирования одной страничке, мне нужно обработать тысяч url на ограниченных ресурсах, если открывать браузеры и использовать Java движок - это очень долго. По PhanomJS - документации мало (!) вот пример TODO нужно сделать когдато :) http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/get-page.html т.е. нет по этому методу НИЧЕГО и по другим вы внимательно изучите сайт и поймете, что для серьезной работы документации нет.

Answer (score 2):

После мучительных поисков было найдено самое простое решение:
1. Чтобы получить полные данные из Phantom JS, а именно "отрендеренную" картинку сайта в HTML в PHP нужно использовать shell_exec (а не просто шел), url, а параметры передавать через пробел (т.е. url который хотите обработать)php:

```
$phantom_script= dirname(__FILE__). '/get-website.js'. ' http://google.com'; 
$response =  shell_exec ('phantomjs ' . $phantom_script);
```

и в JS get-website.js:

```
var args = require('system').args;
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var address = args[1];

page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log(page.content); //content = Null
        console.log('Unable to load the address! PHP');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(page.content);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 1000); // Change timeout as required to allow sufficient time 
    }
});
```

Единственная проблема это cyrrilic (кирилица) после получения контента даже в формате UTF-8 она безнадежно искарежена - но это уже другой вопрос.